# Apps script setting formulas in a grid

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to pass a 2d array of formulas which does not effect all cells. For example if I do not want cell D5 to be effected because it already has a static value how should I pass the 2D array to setFormulas() function. If the code below is used it will overwrite cell D5 with an empty string.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var formulas = [
   ["=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", ""],
   ["=AVERAGE(B2:B4)", "=AVERAGE(C2:C4)", "=AVERAGE(D2:D4)"]
 ];

 var cell = sheet.getRange("B5:D6");
 cell.setFormulas(formulas);
```

Comment: There is no built in way to do that. You will need to do it as two different writes or add the static value to your array.

Comment: You want to read the values of the range and loop through each cell, setting a formula in any empty cell and skipping any which has data, then save the information back to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var value = sheet.getRange("D5").getValue();

 var formulas = [
   ["=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", value],
   ["=AVERAGE(B2:B4)", "=AVERAGE(C2:C4)", "=AVERAGE(D2:D4)"]
 ];

 var cell = sheet.getRange("B5:D6");

 cell.setValues(formulas);
```